# Why does Excel throw an exception on Quit when started from command line?

Tags: windows, excel, vba, cmd

I have a simple Excel file that queries a database when it opens and then closes automatically.

- If I double click the file to open it from within Windows Explorer (I'm running Windows XP and Excel 2002), it works fine.
- However, if I run it using `Excel "C:\DataUpdate.xls"` from Start > Run or from `Shell` within another instance of Excel in a separate file, Excel will crash on exit.

I can't figure out why it does it one scenario and not in the other.

In DataUpdate.xls, I have 2 procedures, `UpdateTable()` and `OnWorkbookOpen()`, which is called from `Workbook_Open()` when the workbook opens.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set qt = ws.Range("A1").QueryTable

qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub

Sub OnWorkbookOpen()
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "DataUpdate.xls" Then
'I put this If statement in so I can change the file's
'name and then edit the file without code
'running.

    UpdateTable
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Excel.Application.Quit
End If


End Sub
```

If I open the file from Windows Explorer, everything is fine.  If I run it from the command line with `Excel "C:\DataUpdate.xls"`, the code runs fine until the application tries to exit with `Application.Quit`, at which point Excel throws an exception.

When I view the details of the error report, here's some of the information I find:

> AppName: excel.exe 
>   AppVer: 10.0.6854.0 
>   ModName: olconnector.dll 
>   ModVer: 2.0.2303.0 
>   Offset: 000114d5

Why is there different behavior based on how I start the application and what can I do so that the application behaves the same regardless of how I start it?

Comment: Instead of checking the filename to descide for/against quitting the application, isn't it much more comfortable to use the "command" string? It gives to the possibility to check for command line arguments? This way you can start Excel with a command line argument like this:

"c:\Programme\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" test.xlsm noQuit

So you do not need to change the name every time. Additionally you can make a new command inside of the popup menu of the Excel filetype.

Comment: Check this http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/05/visual-basic-command-line-arguments.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to play around with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to google olconnector.dll is outlook connector, an office add-in.

http://ask.officelive.com/workspace/qna/t/4578.aspx

Since it is dealing with Outlook, I believe it would have some dependency on the login you are using on the machine.

When you are opening excel, are you using the same credentials as the account you log in to the computer with?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = null;
Process batchProcess = null;

startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Domain = "somedomain";
startInfo.UserName = "Domainuser";
startInfo.Password = "pwd";
```

Not really sure on what the error is, but this is something you could try out.

Comment: I'll be darned if it wasn't the Office Live Add-in that was causing the problem! +1 for the link and thanks for the tip.  I never would have thought something that obscure would have been the cause of the problem.

Comment: Uninstalling the Office Live Add-in v1.3 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I only put command  `application.quit` into function Workbook_Open() it works fine here, when I start it via doubleclick, via command `test.xlsm` as well as via command `"c:\Programme\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" test.xlsm`.

- Did you also try to reduce the problem to only that one command?
- Which command do you use from command line.
- Maybe you can try putting `DoEvents` after `Application.Save` command?
- Did you try to change command `Excel.Application.Quit` to `Application.Quit`? Maybe that's a difference when starting from command line.

I use Excel 2007 on Win XP Pro.

Comment: - I just tried limiting it to just application.quit.  Didn't work.
- From cmd: EXCEL.EXE "C:\DataUpdate.xls"
- Putting DoEvents after Application.Quit did not work
- I changed it to Application.Quit - did not work